# Pauli Matrices & 2D Rotation Operators?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, rotation, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

I was doing a strange calculation with my teacher the other day: find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the 2D rotation operator. Intuitively, there should be no solution to this problem in $\mathbb{R}^2$. However, when we extend to $\mathbb{C}^2$, we find that the unnormalized eigenvectors are:

$$ \vec{v}_1 = (1,i)$$ $$\vec{v}_2 = (1,-i) $$

Then we realized that these vectors are exactly the eigenvectors of one of the Pauli Matrices $\sigma_y$:

$$\left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & -i  \\
i & 0 \\
\end{array} \right)$$

What do we make of that? What happens in other dimensions? Is 2D very special?

Comment: Hello. May I ask what do you mean by " what do we make of that"? Do you want to know how rotations in 2D are useful? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it is trivial. Real $2D$ rotations, viewed both as matrices in $\mathbb R^2$ or $\mathbb C^2$ are all of the form
$$R(\theta)= e^{\theta i\sigma_2}\:.$$
(Notice that $i\sigma_2$ is real antisymmetric as it must be it being a generator of $so(2)$.)
Moreover from the spectral decomposition in $\mathbb C^2$, $e^{\theta i\sigma_2}$ has the same eigenvectors as $\sigma_2$.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the generic dimension part, in case it is not self-evident from Valter's answer:

In *D* dimensions, the rotation matrix is the exponential of an angle *θ* times a matrix **K**, a normalized generator of the corresponding rotation group SO(*D*) around some unit axis *D*-vector ***k***, in the vector representation, so the matrix is *D×D*. The eigenvectors of these matrices **K** will likewise be the eigenvectors of the rotation operator.

However, since there are several (an infinity) axes of rotation for *D*>2, there will be an infinity of eigenvector sets, each characterized by the specific spin matrix **K**.

For instance, in *D*=3, the vector representation, the rotation matrix is given as this exponential of the cross-product matrix 
$$
\mathbf{K}=  
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -k_3 & k_2 \\
k_3 & 0 & -k_1 \\
-k_2 & k_1 & 0
\end{array}\right],$$ 
expanded trivially by the [Rodrigues formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula#Matrix_notation) to just  $\mathbf{R} = \mathbf{I} + (\sin\theta) \mathbf{K} + (1-\cos\theta)\mathbf{K}^2  ~$. Thus the three eigenvectors of **K** (one of which is the null vector ***k***) are also the eigenvectors of **R**.